# makeList and Print functions for a linked list in C++

Tags: c++, string, linked-list

The following is my code for making a list by reading in a list of inputs. It is supposed to return a pointer to the list of strings in the order that they are read in. Then in the print function, I want to print out all the elements in the linked list, stopping when the next of the element is NULL. I don't understand why my code isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 struct Node{
        string val;
        Node* next;
    };

Node* makeList(){
    string value;
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *current = NULL;
    Node *last = NULL;

    while (cin >> value){
        current = new Node();
        if(head== NULL){
            head = current;
        }
        if(last!= NULL){
            last->next=current;
        }
        last=current;
    }
    if(last != NULL) {
        last->next = NULL;
    }
    return head;
}
void printList (Node* p)
{
    Node* tmp = p;

    while(tmp->next != NULL) {
        tmp = tmp->next;
        cout >> tmp->val >> endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about your code isn't working? What is the output you're getting?

Comment: Please **edit** your question and include a description of how it's not working.

Comment: You never put value in the list

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't set `current->val` to `value`:

   ```
   current = new Node();
   current->val = value; // <--
   ```
2. Change the condition in the `while` loop of the `printList()` function from:

   ```
   while (temp->next != NULL)
   ```

   to

   ```
   while (temp != NULL)
   ```

   and switch the two statements and change `>>` to `<<`:

   ```
   while(tmp != NULL) {
       cout << tmp->val << endl;
       tmp = tmp->next;
   }
   ```